# Embed Javadoc Into Websites HTML

Tags: java, html, javadoc, codenameone

I have a rather complex web design with menus and some footer/header data (not to mention CSS/JS etc.). The JavaDocs for our API's have their own design which makes you feel like you've left the website.

I'd like the JavaDocs to be embedded into the website itself, but an iframe isn't quite the way I want to go. More like the Android JavaDoc: http://developer.android.com/reference/packages.html

How do I accomplish something like that?

I tried working with [doclava](https://code.google.com/p/doclava/wiki/GettingStarted), but its really unclear if and how I can use my own design for the output from their wiki?

Comment: I disagree with the duplicate flag here. I didn't find that question initially but it isn't marked as answered and indeed it isn't. I tried the doclava mentioned there and it doesn't produce that.

Comment: Isn't a bounty the way to get attention back on that issue then?

Comment: I didn't find the previous question despite searching and it didn't popup as I looked, I doubt it would be visible. Regardless its a different question that's more specific than my generic question.

Answer (score 0):

Can you determine the main style elements in the javadoc and replace those with your own css classes(for example styles borders and tables)?  Android documentation that you mention uses the parent site's styles.